# Lithium ion battery life

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging, usb-device, battery-lifespan

We are developing a device for automobile cabin use. It has 2 modes of operation, the first mode is where our device will be powered by the automobile battery through the USB port of the vehicle. The second mode will be powered by a 11.1 V rechargeable li-ion battery. **The issue in this is that, the second mode would have scarce use at times because of which the battery would remain stale and unused during those times which could even last a month. Also our battery would remain charged fully during this scenario and only will be cut off from the power supply through its BMS. Is this harmful for battery life or it would'nt affect the battery life much?**

Edit: Yes its similar to a cordless power tool in the perspective of it getting charged and used.

Comment: Is a Lithium-Ion really necessary for this? it doesn't sound like it is.

Comment: Yes it is, because in the second mode the device needs to be used as a vaccum cleaner and it cant be corded to the vehicle usb socket, hence to make it mobile a battery is needed.

Comment: _" our battery would remain charged fully during this scenario and **only will be Cut off from the power supply through its bms**."_ - exaclty how will the BMS 'cut off' the battery from the power supply?

Comment: By saying cut off, what i mean to say is it would prevent overcharging.

Comment: There are more battery chemistries you could expore. Especially ones that can deal with the summer heat in the car better.

Comment: It sounds like what you are developing is a cordless vacuum cleaner that can recharge itself from a USB port. I don't see how this is very different from any other cordless power tool. Don't reply in the comments. Clarify in the question.

Comment: Will the BMS cut off on overvoltage rather than a charger doing CC-CV-cutoff?

Comment: LiIon like to be stored at 80% for maximum life.  Windows 10 & beyond even (usually) have a setting you can limit your charge to 80% to extend the lifetime of the battery.  '

Comment: @KyleB So a vacuum cleaner running Windows 10? I know some of us have a poor opinion of Windows but to run a vac?

Comment: @SolarMike   I think you're trying to be funny, but in case you're not I'll be more clear...   The "80%" figure is so ubiquitous in LiIon battery usage that it's built into the windows operating system.    I only mean to point out a concrete example of where such a setting is implemented.  Obviously it doesn't matter what the application is.